# Highcharts not working

Tags: 8, charts

I am using the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module for displaying charts in my Drupal project. 
When I took the `chart API example module page`, it's not displaying any. It throws me this error (in the console):

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function

[image]

Any idea on how to resolve this issue? Or is there anything additional to do after installing the module?

I enabled all the sub-modules of the Chart module:

[image]

And I selected `Highcharts` as the Charting library option:

[image]

Notes:

- I added the chart js file inside `charts/modules/charts_api_example` and referenced the `charts_highcharts.js` file in the `charts_api_example.libraries.yml` file.
- I think the issue may be because jQuery must be loaded before Highcharts when checked the view source on the API examples page the jQuery is loaded at last after the Highcharts library. Not sure though that's the issue.

Comment: Is the highcharts JS library available? Is the library itself loaded?

Comment: @Kevin yea I added the chart js file inside `charts/modules/charts_api_example` and referenced the `charts_highcharts.js` file in the `charts_api_example.libraries.yml` file

Comment: Sorry i don't know why the question is downvoted ?

Comment: Beats me. What does the README say about any setup steps?

Comment: @Kevin yea I run as what said in the README file, I cd to the `charts/modules/charts_api_example` submodule and run **composer require --prefer-dist google/charts:45** after modifying the composer.json in the **repositories** section by adding `google_charts` package

Comment: I think the issue may be because **jQuery must be loaded before highcharts** when checked the view source on the API examples page the jQuery is loaded at last after the highcharts library. Not sure though thats the issue.

Comment: Actually you are not supposed to add or edit anything inside the charts module. Why did you add a `charts_api_example.libraries.yml` and what's in it? Then the example module only lists `charts:charts` as dependency. Did you activate any other sub-module then that loads on of the libraries at all?

Comment: Yes i tried google chart module and selected it as a charting library option.Then it throws me **google not defined** error or so. Thats why i doubted whether jQuery is making problem

Comment: similarly I am getting **Uncaught ReferenceError: bb is not defined** for billboard.js and **Uncaught ReferenceError: c3 is not defined** for c3.js **Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined** for charts.js

Comment: Please don't put answers in the question body, you can just add an answer if you've solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was thoroughly mistaken about the installation of the charts. After installation, I was editing the repositories section in `composer.json`  and running the composer command to install the specific library (eg: `composer require --prefer-dist highcharts/highcharts:6.0.4`) from the particular sub-module. But **it has to be done from the Drupal project root directory**. Appreciate your valuable time and expecting this will help others.